# How to define date in variable

Tags: php, mysql

How to make `$data = CURDATE();`. I want to make something like that or maybe here I need to edit: `if(mysqli_query("UPDATE users set data='$data'"))`

Comment: You're going to need to clarify this a great deal. Do you mean you want to update your `users` table to set `data` to be the current date/time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURDATE()` is a MySQL function. You use it in a query like this:

```
UPDATE user SET some_date=CURDATE() WHERE id = 1;
```

If you want to use it from PHP you use the `date()` function. Call it like this to get the date in the standard international date format:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

You can pass different format strings to the PHP date function, MySQL stores the date with an internal date representation and formats the output depending on how you have configured your connection.

Comment: Thank you! Yea, I'm using php and $date = date('Y-m-d'); worked.

Comment: @ZygisGamer Why do you need the PHP variable? Why not just use `set data = CURDATE()` in the query?